# how to interact with obj or collada-model in AFrame

Tags: webvr, aframe

```
<a-assets>
        <a-mixin id="ring" geometry="primitive: ring; radiusOuter: 0.20;
                radiusInner: 0.15;"
                material="color: cyan; shader: flat"
                cursor=" fuse: true"></a-mixin>
        <a-asset-item id="mancloth" src="../models/man.obj"></a-asset-item>
        <a-asset-item id="manclothmtl" src="../models/man.mtl"></a-asset-item>
</a-assets>
<a-entity camera look-controls wasd-controls><a-entity mixin="ring" position="0 0 -3">
        <a-animation begin="cursor-click" easing="ease-in" attribute="scale"
               fill="backwards" from="0.3 0.3 0.3" to="1 1 1"></a-animation>
        <a-animation begin="cursor-fusing" easing="ease-in" attribute="scale"
               fill="forwards" from="1 1 1" to="0.3 0.3 0.3"></a-animation>
      </a-entity>
</a-entity>
<a-obj-model  scale="1 1 1" src="#mancloth" mtl="#manclothmtl"></a-obj-model>
```

I use the camera to interact with the obj but aframe.js shows an error on line 57766. How can I solve this problem without changing aframe.js.

```
var intersectedEl = intersection.object.el;
intersectedEl.emit('raycaster-intersected', {el: el,intersection:intersection});
```

`intersection.object` is a THREE.Mesh, so intersection.object.el is undefined!

Answer (score 1):

This problem has been fixed at https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/pull/1497 by binding the A-Frame entity to each child of the model.

You can wait for A-Frame 0.3.0 or use the latest A-Frame master. Right now, the cursor uses a raycaster to see what object was intersected. With OBJ/COLLADA models, it creates a tree of objects. However, A-Frame was only treating the top-level object as an entity. So when the raycaster returned the object, it did not have an associated entity to emit an event with.

Now it should just work:

```
<a-camera><a-cursor></a-cursor></a-camera>
<a-obj-model></a-obj-model>
```